# Remove the "clickability" from a link (anchor tag)

Tags: javascript, dom-events

I have a couple of links, which need a few seconds to process before sending the response, so i'd like to implement an indicator icon. Here's my starting point:

```
<a href="/foo"><img src="icon.png" /></a>
```

It's a legacy app, and the code already is a mess, so I don't mind and use an inline event handler:

```
<a href="/foo"><img src="icon.png" onclick="indicate(this)" /></a>
```

Also, there's no JS framework tied in. I could use some other mechanics to apply the event handler, but that won't alter the problem I'm trying to solve.

Since the backend processing consumes lot of resources, I want to keep the user from clicking multiple times. I tried to remove the href attribute on first click. It seems, by using a timeout the href is removed properly after sending the request, but both Firefox and IE9 allow me to click the link again.

Here's the `indicate()` function:

```
function indicate(e) {
    if (indicator.ref.nodeName) indicateStop();
    
    // save state
    indicator.ref = e;
    indicator.orig.href = indicator.ref.parentNode.href;
    indicator.orig.src = indicator.ref.src;
    
    // replace icon
    indicator.ref.src = indicator.src;
    
    // remove href
    setTimeout(function(){ indicator.ref.parentNode.removeAttribute("href"); }, 20);
}
```

So the question is, how can I remove the "clickability" from a link (anchor) by clicking it?

Comment: Did you try returning false in the on click event handler? That should do it I think.

Comment: Disable the default event [`event.preventDefault`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/event.preventDefault) and handle it yourself (you should also probably change the cursor appearance to `default` when you disable the link).

Comment: @steveax Does that mean i'd have to handle the anchor target lookup myself, too? - Also, the cursor already changes back, and the href is not set anymore when i click the second time.

Comment: Why change the cursor? It looks like the link is still to behave as a button.

Comment: Yes, you'd have to handle the url request yourself. @popnoodles, if the link is disabled, it shouldn't have the pointer cursor as this is a cue to the user that clicking will do something.

Comment: I am under the impression the link still does something otherwise why is he/she binding a click event? User still needs to know "yes, click this"

Comment: I'd accept steveax's comment as an answer. Just sayin

Answer (score 0):

With this code you can stop anchors from opening the links:

```
$('a').on('click', function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
});
```

Comment: that looks awfully like jquery. OP seems to be using vanilla.

Comment: It still looks awfully like jQuery!

Comment: i like to use jquery because i hate javascript on the html, and i find it nicer to assign a event to a array os elements this way.

Comment: I like jQuery too, but i'm working on a legacy app. The "don't look at it, don't think about it" rule applies. Adding/removing a rotating gif should be possible without using a framework.

Comment: " i hate javascript on the html, and i find it nicer to assign a event to a array " then supplying an answer using jQuery is no use when the question doesn't specify jQuery. You can still do it without javascript in the HTML without using jQuery.

Answer (score 0):

You could try setting `pointer-events` property to `none` on first click and restore it to default after the aforementioned backend processing is done. For instance

```js
function indicate(el) {
  el.style.pointerEvents = 'none';
  
  // Simulate a long running operation
  setTimeout(() => {
    el.style.pointerEvents = 'auto';
  }, 2000);
}
```

```html
<a href="javascript:void" onclick="indicate(this)">
  <img src="icon.png" />
</a>
```

Answer (score -1):

```
<a id="indicate" href="/foo"><img src="icon.png" /></a>

document.getElementById('indicate').addEventListener('click', indicate, false);

function indicate(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
}
```

Some people will say to use return false, which is sometimes fine but not always the best idea.
[event.preventDefault() vs. return false](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1357118/event-preventdefault-vs-return-false)

Comment: In my case, e actually is the element i clicked on.. so there is no e.preventDefault()